# phonegap app not opening links

Tags: android, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I just started my first phonegap application with a html5 mobile website template.

I deployed it but external links are not working on the app. When i click a link just nothing happens.

I added inappbrowser and whitelist plugin to app.

I've added this code to head section of html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
}
</script>
```

and here how i create a link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank',);" class="logo-css"></a>
```

What should i do to make this work? thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('apache.org', '_blank');" class="logo-css"></a>
```

or better:

```
document.getElementById('yourlink').on('click', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   window.open('apache.org', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but still not working. it's working on browser but not working on adroid app

Comment: <body class="dual-sidebar"> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
};
        document.getElementById('gazi').on('click', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   window.open('apache.org', '_blank');
});
</script> is this on right place? and i tried two links both not working. a href="#" class="footer-logo" id="gazi">asda</a>
                 <a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');" class="kosgeb-logo"></a>

Comment: try to define everything inside the deviceready listener. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4kLfak5/) here.

Comment: still not working :( you can see https://jsfiddle.net/r0yhgttq/ for both html and js part. not opening any link on mobile app